# how do i know where to send item bought on my websites

Tags: e-commerce, web-development-server, mobile-development

When a costumer buys something from a website how does the owner know where to send the items purchased and is there a way to get notification to my phone when a purchase is made from my website

Comment: The question you posted is way to broad to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

when a user buy something on the website the owner will get the adress that the user had type in the fields -_- the HTML page will send with a POST the content of the fields to a PHP file on the server.

the form :

```
<form action="post.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="item" value="the item that you buy"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="adress" value="your adress"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

an example of the php file:

```
<?php 

$item=$_POST['item'];
$user_adress=$_POST['adress'];

echo $item;
echo $user_adress;

?>
```

for the notification on your phone, you can create a page who display the information of a buy. but get a push notification on your phone will be more harder to do